# Слияние конкретного коммита бранча в master

Tags: git, git-merge

При выполнении слияния `git merge --no-ff develop` все предыдущие коммиты ветки develop так же становятся коммитами master-а. Есть ли возможность сделать слияние так, чтобы в мастере были только те коммиты, которыми я делаю слияние?

P.S. Пользуюсь bitbucket-ом и графикой показано все верно, у одной линии 2 точки (видимо, master), у второй несколько (видимо, develop) и она втекает во вторую точку первой линии, но все коммиты помечены и как develop, и как master.

Comment: @Kosterio, у каждого коммита есть вполне конкретный parent, если вы сливаете ветки, то вся разница веток должна появиться в конечной ветке. Есть, конечно, cherry-pick, но мне сдается, вы просто неверно понимаете концепцию git. Ветки - это не более чем указатели на конкретные коммиты, и история ветки не содержится в самой ветке.

Больше [здесь](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%3F)

Comment: @Etk Концепцию я понимаю. При таком слиянии на сайте пишется правильно, что у него 2 родителя, как и должно быть. По факту мне просто нужно, чтобы при фильтре мастера отображало только 2 коммита

Comment: @Kosterio судя по всему, нет, потому что я уже написал, что ветка не управляет своей историей и что включение одного коммита автоматом включает всех его родителей до тех пор, пока это не делается через cherry-pick, interactive rebase или аналог, которые, насколько понимаю, побьют вам исходный код, если просто выцеплять единичный коммит.

Comment: @Etk Ну теоретически можно после мерджа через ребэйз ветки мастера сделать скваш необходимых коммитов и в мастере будут только нужные коммиты. Но это геморно, и в принципе я понял, что и бесполезно.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы имели в виду `git cherry-pick develop`. В этом случае слияния не будет, но изменения из последнего коммита из develop применятся. Как и при слиянии, при `cherry-pick` возможны конфликты.

Таким образом можно избирательно переносить некоторые коммиты из одной ветки в другую. Обычно последующему слиянию такие перенесённые коммиты не мешают.

Применять таким образом можно не обязательно последний коммит из develop. Помимо `develop` там также может быть, например, полный ID коммита.